# Refresh page layout after receiving Admob banner event

Tags: angularjs, admob, onsen-ui

Currently, I am experimenting with Onsen-UI + AngularJS + Admob `[com.admob.AdmobPlugin (1.0.0)]` + Cordova. I am having my banner at the bottom of the screen.

When there are lots of contents on a page, it is nice to have the page automagically become scrollable. However, the Admob banner is simply overlapping with the Onsen-UI webpage. Therefore, the contents at the bottom of the page are always blocked by the banner.

I have tried adding a `<div id="admobSpace"></div>`, and then update its height just after receiving the ad banner by `angular.element(document.querySelector('#admobSpace')).attr('height', admobAd.AD_SIZE.BANNER.height + 'px');` without success.

Can anyone please give me some pointers on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have finally got it working now.

In the `ons.ready()` function,

```
var admobDiv = document.getElementById('admobSpace');
angular.element(admobDiv).css({
    'bottom': '0px',
    'height': admobAd.AD_SIZE.BANNER.height + 'px',
    'width': '100%',
    'background-color': 'black'
});
```